# php explode issues

Tags: php, html, explode, submit-button

I have written a small php script which reads file names from a directory, uses explode to get rid of the extension and then displays the file name on a php page.

But for some reason, whenever the file name consists of more than one word, it only shows the first word of the file name.

Here is the code,

```
while  ($name = readdir ($handle)) 
        {
            if ($name == '.' || $name == '..')
            continue; /* don't echo anything, skip to next read */
            $i++;
            echo '<td >';
            echo '<form name="form" method="get" action="download.php">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="file" value='.$name.' />';
            $parts=explode(".",$name);
            $name=$parts[0];
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value='.$name.' class="subbutton" /> </br></br>';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</td>';
            if($i==5)
            {
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
            $i=0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You aren't quoting the `value` in your `input`. The HTML is treating anything after a space in a filename as a separate attribute.

Comment: You should really not be mixing your logic and HTML this way. You should build an array of files to display in a single loop, and actually output the results with a second loop rather than merging it all together this way.

Comment: Checkout the built-in pathinfo and basename function for parsing filepath/filename information into the constituent pieces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value='.$name.' class="subbutton" /> </br></br>';
```

to this:

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.$name.'" class="subbutton" /> </br></br>';
```

That way you're quoting your attribute and the HTML parser can't get confused by spaces in your filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure you get everything to the left of the last period in the file name, since file names can include more than one. This makes explode a less-than-ideal solution. The following code will give you the name of the file, minus the file extension:

```
$file_name_without_extension = substr($full_file_name, 0, strrpos($full_file_name, "."));
```